# How can I add combobox to datagridview using this code? VB.NET

Tags: datagridview, vb.net-2010

This is my code for showing data in the data gridview and some of the data that it will show requires just a yes/no answer so I wanted to add a combobox to limit the choices:

```
    Dim con As SqlConnection
    Dim adap As SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As DataSet
    Dim cmdbl As SqlCommandBuilder


  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Call populateCombo()
        Try
            con = New SqlConnection
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=mssql;Initial Catalog=VRC_Royalty;User ID=sa;Password="
            con.Open()

            adap = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM tblsongmasterfile ORDER BY Primaryid ASC", con)
            ds = New System.Data.DataSet()
            adap.Fill(ds, "Song_list")
            DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error\n" + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a `GridViewComboBoxColumn` you need to do something like:

```
Dim cmb As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn()
cmb.HeaderText = "Yes or No"
cmb.Name = "cmb"
cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2
cmb.Items.Add("Yes")
cmb.Items.Add("No")
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb)
```

If the data for this column is retrieved in your query, you may want to look into disabling `AutoGenerateColumns` and manually adding each column in desired order.